# Am I implementing this remove node function for a doubly linked list in C correctly?

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am learning about doubly linked lists. I have implemented a remove node function that works correctly, and is intended to work whether the node to be deleted is the first node, the last node, or any node between. However, I am wondering if my logic is correct (efficient I should say). I have had some trouble pinpointing a definitive example for properly performing this function.  This linked list does not keep track of the tail as an FYI. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
Node *removeNode(Node *head, int d)
{
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL){
        if (curr->data == d){
            if (curr->prev == NULL && curr->next == NULL){
                free(curr);
                head = NULL;
                return head;
            } else if (curr->prev == NULL){
                curr->next->prev = NULL;
                head = curr->next;
                free(curr);
                return head;
            } else if (curr->next == NULL){
                curr->prev->next = NULL;
                free(curr);
                return head;
            } else if (curr->prev != NULL && curr->next != NULL){
                curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
                curr->prev->next = curr->next;
                free(curr);
                return head;
            }
        } else if (curr->data != d){
            curr = curr->next;
        }           
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the test in `else if (curr->data != d)` as you only get to the `else` clause if `curr->data != d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code works correctly; that's good.  And [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) gives it a clean bill of health, at least when run with the support code I created.  However, it can be simplified.

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
};

static Node *removeNode(Node *head, int d)
{
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->data != d)
            curr = curr->next;
        else
        {
            if (curr->prev != NULL)
                curr->prev->next = curr->next;
            else
                head = curr->next;
            if (curr->next != NULL)
                curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
            free(curr);
            return head;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

static Node *addNodeAtHead(Node *head, int d)
{
    Node *item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
    if (item != 0)
    {
        item->next = head;
        item->prev = NULL;
        if (head != 0)
            head->prev = item;
        item->data = d;
    }
    return item;
}

static void dumpList(const char *tag, Node *head)
{
    printf("%s:", tag);
    while (head != 0)
    {
        printf(" %d", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    Node *head = 0;
    head = addNodeAtHead(head, 23);
    head = addNodeAtHead(head, 43);
    head = addNodeAtHead(head, 73);
    head = addNodeAtHead(head, 13);
    head = addNodeAtHead(head, 33);
    dumpList("Full", head);

    head = removeNode(head, 33);
    dumpList("Lost 33", head);
    head = removeNode(head, 23);
    dumpList("Lost 23", head);
    head = removeNode(head, 13);
    dumpList("Lost 13", head);
    head = removeNode(head, 34);
    dumpList("Lost 34", head);
    head = removeNode(head, 43);
    dumpList("Lost 43", head);
    head = removeNode(head, 73);
    dumpList("Lost 73", head);
    head = removeNode(head, 37);
    dumpList("Lost 37", head);

    return 0;
}
```

The fundamental difference is that the code above avoids dealing with the special cases specially, to the maximum extent feasible.

- If the previous node is not null, then adjust the previous node's next pointer to point to the next node (and it doesn't matter whether the next node is null or not);
- otherwise, the head has to change to point to the next node (and it still doesn't matter whether the next node is null or not).
- If the next node is not null, then adjust the next node's previous pointer to point to the previous node (and it doesn't matter whether the previous node is null or not).
- Then free the current node and return the head node.

An example output when run on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.5:

```
$ make dl61 && valgrind --suppressions=etc/suppressions-macos-10.12.5 -- ./dl61
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes dl61.c -o dl61 
==3505== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3505== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3505== Using Valgrind-3.13.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3505== Command: ./dl61
==3505== 
Full: 33 13 73 43 23
Lost 33: 13 73 43 23
Lost 23: 13 73 43
Lost 13: 73 43
Lost 34: 73 43
Lost 43: 73
Lost 73:
Lost 37:
==3505== 
==3505== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3505==     in use at exit: 22,308 bytes in 163 blocks
==3505==   total heap usage: 184 allocs, 21 frees, 28,572 bytes allocated
==3505== 
==3505== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3505==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3505==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3505==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3505==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3505==         suppressed: 22,308 bytes in 163 blocks
==3505== 
==3505== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3505== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 5 from 5)
$
```

Code is seldom so good that it cannot be improved.  I think this variant of `removeNode()` is a little tidier.  It has the loop solely worrying about iterating over the list to find the (first) node to be deleted.  Then, if a node was found, it deletes it, outside the body of the loop.  This code requires the `<assert.h>` header too as written (but it hasn't fired yet).

```
static Node *removeNode(Node *head, int d)
{
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL && curr->data != d)
        curr = curr->next;
    if (curr != NULL)
    {
        assert(curr->data == d);
        if (curr->prev != NULL)
            curr->prev->next = curr->next;
        else
            head = curr->next;
        if (curr->next != NULL)
            curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
        free(curr);
    }
    return head;
}
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: Awesome! I apologize for not thanking you sooner. I am presently analyzing (studying) your code to get a good grasp on it so that I make sure I understand it when I swap it out for mine.

Comment: Thank you, I drew out your code to visualize the conditions and it makes much more sense and a lot more compact/less redundant.

Comment: @cyberguy: You can see a re-refactored version of the code in https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-4507-0304.  The file `dl71.c` separates the node deletion from finding the node.  The code in `dl59.c` is basically what you wrote with the test harness added; `dl61.c` is the first answer here, and `dl67.c` is the second version shown here.  The refactored code is arguably better than the previous versions.  And there's no obligation to look at any of it.